# How to customize linux mint cinnamon 19 login screen

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login, theme

I would like to know if there is a way to customize the Linux mint login screen. And by customize I don't mean the background, but for example can I move the password input box to the middle instead of the left of the screen, or make the entire login screen look like the one from Ubuntu or Xubuntu for example?

Comment: look here https://www.gnome-look.org/search/projectSearchText/login

Comment: Thanks. But I must say that there is nothing good there. Every one is either too simple or just plain childish.

Comment: you are missing the point ..... look at the contents of the tar files to learn how to format your own login screen

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try that out